# C++ Form Build error

Tags: forms, c++-cli

Today we've been starting to use C++ and we've encountered a problem with creating our form.

I've been looking at a video which contains a tutorial how to make a Form in C++.
I'm used to use C# instead of C++, so I'm really a beginner of the beginning.
I've set my SubSystem to Windows and my EntryPoint to main.

I've used this code:

```
 #include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


[STAThread]
void main(array<String^>^ args) 
{

    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Project1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

In the MyForm.cpp

The errors:

> Error  5   error C2065: 'form' : undeclared identifier
>   Error   6   error C2065: 'form' : undeclared identifier
>   Error   3   error C2065: 'MyForm' : undeclared identifier
>   Error   4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'form'
>   Error   2   error C2653: 'Project1' : is not a class or namespace name
>   8   IntelliSense: expected a ';'
>   9   IntelliSense: identifier "form" is undefined
>   7   IntelliSense: name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
>   Warning 1   warning C4829: Possibly incorrect parameters to function main. Consider 'int main(Platform::Array^ argv)'

I apologise for not posting an image due to my lack of reputation...

I haven't configured anything further than this.
Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Sjors

Comment: It doesn't find the declaration of Project1::MyForm, add the reference of the related assembly and use the namespace

Comment: Note that you are not actually using C++, but C++/CLI. These are two different languages.

Comment: @Matt Thank you very much, you've got me thinking about what could be wrong. And I/you fixed it! Have a great day!

Comment: `array<String^>^` is mainly a C++/CLI type, but the type recommended by IntelliSense, `Platform::Array`, is a C++/CX type. Are you sure you're using the right compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Changed Project1 to Test100920141327, which is my project name, just a really dumb thing actually. I didn't know the Project1 was a name of your project. Thanks everyone for supporting!

```
 #include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


[STAThread]
void main(array<String^>^ args) 
{

    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Test100920141327::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Kind regards,

Sjors

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it in this way:

In the properties window of my project I set the *Configuration* drop-down list to **Active(Debug)**. Originally it was **Debug** in my case.